# Count letter differences of two strings Python

Tags: python, string

I'm having some problems with an exercise about strings in python.

I have 2 different lists:

```
list1= "ABCDEFABCDEF"
```

and

```
list2= "AZBYCXDWEVFABCDEF"
```

I need to compare those 2 lists according to their position so the 1 letter together, then the 2...using the min length (so here length of list1) and store the letters in a new variable according to if they are different or the same.

```
identicals=[]
different=[]
```

I tried to code something and it seems to find the same ones, but doesn't work on the different ones since it copies them multiple times.

```
for x in list1:
   for y in list2:
       if list1>list2:
           if x==y:
               identicals.append(x)
           if x!=y :
               different.append(x)          
       if list2>list1:
           if y==x:
               identicals.append(y)
           if y!=x:
               different.append(y)
```

**EDIT**: Output result should be something like this:

```
identicals=['A']
different=["Z","B","Y","C","X","D","W","E","V",F","A"]
```

The thing is that the letter A is only shown on identicals but not in different even if F!=A.

Comment: What's your expected output for that sample data? They only match at the start, so `identicals` would get 'A' and all the other chars would go in to `different`. Is that what you want? BTW, it's confusing to call two strings `list1` and `list2`.

Comment: Welcome to SO!  I see that you've got the answer you needed.  Rather than edit your question, please consider upvoting good answers and accepting the most helpful one.  See http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers for more advice.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting unwanted duplicates because you have a nested pair of `for` loops, so each item in `list2` get tested for *every* item in `list1`.

The key idea is to iterate over the two strings in *parallel*. You can do that with the built-in [`zip` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip), which yields a tuple of the corresponding items from each iterable you feed it, stopping as soon as one of the iterables runs out of items.

From your example code, it looks like you want to take the items for the `different` list from the longer string. To do that efficiently, figure out which string is the longer *before* you start looping.

I've renamed your strings because it's confusing to give strings a name starting with "list".

```
s1 = "ABCDEFABCDEF"
s2 = "AZBYCXDWEVFABCDEF"

identicals = [] 
different = []

small, large = (s1, s2) if len(s1) <= len(s2) else (s2, s1)

for x, y in zip(small, large):
    if x == y:
        identicals.append(y)
    else:
        different.append(y)

print(identicals)
print(different)
```

**output**

```
['A']
['Z', 'B', 'Y', 'C', 'X', 'D', 'W', 'E', 'V', 'F', 'A']
```

We can make the `for` loop more compact at the expense of readability. We put our destination lists into a tuple and then use the equality test to select which list in that tuple to append to. This works because `False` has a numeric value of 0, and `True` has a numeric value of 1.

```
for x, y in zip(small, large):
    (different, identicals)[x == y].append(y)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the inner loop. You are comparing each of the letters in list1 with all the letters of list2.

Instead you should have a single loop:

```
identicals=[] 
different=[]
short_list = list1 if len(list1)<= len(list2) else list2
for i in range(len(short_list):
    if list1[i] == list2[i]:
        identicals.append(list1[i])
    else:
        different.append(short_list[i])
```

Comment: btw, don't name string variables with the name "listX"

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
a = "ABCDEFABCDEF"
b = "AZBYCXDWEVFABCDEF"


import numpy
A = numpy.array(list(a))
B = numpy.array(list(b))
common = A[:len(B)] [ (A[:len(B)] == B[:len(A)]) ]
different = A[:len(B)] [ - (A[:len(B)] == B[:len(A)]) ]

>>> list(common)
['A']

>>> list(different)
['B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F']
```